# Create a list from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Another Python noob here with a question.  I have a python nested dictionary that looks like this: (I separated the approved_apps list just to make it easier to read)

```
approved_apps= [
{'app_key_id':9991,'app_name':'Posts','app_path':'/posts'},
{'app_key_id':8881,'app_name':'Tasks','app_path':'/tasks'},
{'app_key_id':7771,'app_name':'Projects','app_path':'/projects'}]

user_profile = {
'user_info':
{'user_lname':'Doe','user_fname':'John','user_email':'johndoe@gmail.com'},
'user_privileges':approved_apps}
```

and I want to extract the app_key_id from the user_profile dictionary so I can have a list that looks like this:

```
desired_result = [9991,8881,7771]
```

I tried dict.items() and list comprehensions but couldn't get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over and access each dict using the key:

```
[d["app_key_id"] for d in approved_apps]#

[9991, 8881, 7771]
```

If there may be dicts that don't have the key to avoid a key error use a `if "app_key_id" in d`

```
[d["app_key_id"] for d in approved_apps if "app_key_id" in d ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution if you want to retrieve 'app_key_id' from 'user_profile' which holds 'approved_apps'

```
approved_apps= [
{'app_key_id':9991,'app_name':'Posts','app_path':'/posts'},
{'app_key_id':8881,'app_name':'Tasks','app_path':'/tasks'},
{'app_key_id':7771,'app_name':'Projects','app_path':'/projects'}]

user_profile = {
'user_info':
{'user_lname':'Doe','user_fname':'John','user_email':'johndoe@gmail.com'},
'user_privileges':approved_apps}

app_key_id=None

for k,v in user_profile.items():
    app_key_id=[result['app_key_id'] for result in v if type(v) is list and 'app_key_id' in result]

print app_key_id
```